# What should we write instead of cv.imencode?

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

I see this error `imencode` is not a function.

I use `opencv.js` in my code and when i called `onOpenCvReady` function:

```
function onOpenCvReady() {
    console.log('onOpenCvReady called');
    cv = window.cv;
    console.log('cv initialized');
}
```

i recived these 2 log's answer on Debugger:

```
onOpenCvReady called
cv initialized
```

but my problem is in Debugger, i see this error: **Uncaught TypeError: `cv.imencode` is not a function**
i use all version `opencv.js` and my problem still on Debugger
how can i fix it?
this line my code:

```
cv.imencode(".jpg", mat, encodedImage, params);
```

What should we write instead of `cv.imencode`?

Comment: Have you checked that `cv` is actually a reference to opencv.js as you're expecting it to be? The error would imply that it isn't and that you need to correct your reference

Answer (score 0):

when I couldn't use `imencode` in `opencv.js`, I use **canvas** in HTML to get data from the image and process it.